# How to make a statement that checks if there's a response to an item in a google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to make some kind of statement that checks if an item in the form has a response or not. Like if the item has no response it does nothing further but if it does it will continue on.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Research the [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) installable trigger. It returns the question names and values from the form submission; you can check whether you question/value is included or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the documentation

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

You will find a couple of useful methods. So, [getItemResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getitemresponses)  returns a string object and allows you to check if the string is not empty (which would mean that there is no response) .

Example code:

```
    // This code gets all the form responses and checks if the response to question number 3 empty

    function myFunction() 
{
   // Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
var form = FormApp.openById('1DUR5CfnI3Dk3LfFC4tiYJiaKRGd1DViYwQBWi9jxC4A');
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
var formResponse; 
var itemResponses;
var itemResponse;
  //i loops through different submissions of a form, e.g. if 3 users submitted a form - there will be three entries for formResponse
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++)
 {
  formResponse = formResponses[i];
  itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  // j loops through the different questions of each submitted form
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) 
   {
    itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    // the if loop checks if the response is an empty string
    if(j==2&&(itemResponse.getResponse()==""||itemResponse.getResponse()==" "))
    {  
     Logger.log('There is no response for question %s in form submission #%s', (j + 1).toString(),(i + 1).toString())
    }
   }   
  }
}
```

Useful for you could be also [isRequired()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#isRequired()) 
to make the response to a question obligatory and thus, make sure that there will be a response to the item. Hope this helps!